# Slim 3 how to use logger inside middleware function

Tags: php, logging, slim

I have written this router after creating everything using the official:

`$ php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton [my-app-name]`

this is my `routes.php` file

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__."/../bootstrap.php");
// Routes

class OwnsPost
{
  /**
   * Example middleware invokable class
   *
   * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request  PSR7 request
   * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface      $response PSR7 response
   * @param  callable                                 $next     Next middleware
   *
   * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
   */
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {


    if($request->getQueryParams() && $request->getQueryParams()['pid']){
      $pid = intval($request->getQueryParams()['pid']);
      if($pid == 0){
        $this->logger->info("illegal pid call");
        return false;
      }
      $cpost = get_post($pid);
      if($cpost->post_author != get_current_user()){
        $this->logger->info("wrong current user, tried accessing postid " . $cpost->ID . " with user ". get_current_user());
        return false;
      }
    }else{
      $this->logger->info("illegal pid call");
      return false;
    }
//    $response->getBody()->write('BEFORE');

    $response = $next($request, $response);
//    $response->getBody()->write('AFTER');

    return $response;
  }
}


$app->get('/campaignedit/setcharitable/{id}', function ($request, $response, $id) {
    // Sample log message
    $this->logger->info("setcharitable '/' route " . $id);

    // Render index view
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index2.php', $id);
})->add( new OwnsPost() );
```

`$this->logger` works in the routing section, but not in the middleware section.

I get an

> Fatal error: Call to a member function info() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/japi/src/routes.php on line 33

Answer (score 1):

There is no member variable `$logger` in your middleware class. So, first add one.

```
protected $logger;
```

Next, add a constructor that accepts `$logger` as an argument.

```
public function __construct($logger) 
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Last, when you initialize your middleware, pass the instance of your Logger.

```
$ownsPost = new OwnsPost($this->logger);
```

Comment: can I actually reuse `$ownsPost` ? because if not, this would be very very insecure.

Comment: or you want me to create `$ownsPost` for every instance? every route a line extra to pass the  logger?

Comment: so basically: hand the slim container into the middleware otherwise we have no access at all to the services.

Comment: Yes, you can re-use your middleware. And yes, you can instead pass the container rather than the logger.

Answer (score -2):

I need obviously to call to 
`global $app`

Comment: Along what @Mikey suggests is a better solution. If you already doing OO programming with class and objects, don't mix in `global` — ever.

Comment: so I have to pass a logger in EACH bloody middleware object? how does that makes any sense to you if it is the same object anyways?

Comment: Seriously, how much middleware have you got?

Comment: You could let all of your route classes (controllers) inherit from a base controller on the base controller you have `static public $app`. You set this value once in `middleware.php` like `BaseController::$app = $app;` then it will be available to all your controllers.

Comment: @Michael what is the reason to use `__get`? i've never used it before

Comment: @Toskan [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) is referred to as a _magic method_. Basically all attempts to access a property that does not exist will invoke this function. Similar there is `__set()` and `__call()` for methods that doesn't exist. Several other exists. See the `Arrgh` class in [mblarsen/arrgh](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh) how it is used to resolve several method names into the same function call: array_flip, flip, arrayFlip, etc all calls the same function without any of the functions have been declared.